# CSS pseudo-class :focus trouble with multiple select on Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm trying to style a `<select multiple>'s` :focus pseudo-class, but on Google Chrome, when I click on the first element, the focus doesn't seem to fire. With the first element still focused, if I click on any other element, it seems to fire, but doens't play the transition.

If the select gains focus by any other mean (clicking on any element but the first, or even on the scroll bar), the focus animation seems to fire normally.

html:

```
<select id="slt" class="selectInput" multiple>
    <option value="">
        --SELECT AN OPTION--
    </option>
    <option value="ALL">
        --ALL--
    </option>
    <option value="1">
        ONE
    </option>
    <option value="2">
        TWO
    </option>
    <option value="3">
        THREE
    </option>
    <option value="4">
        FOUR
    </option>
</select>
```

css:

```
.selectInput
{
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #02659B 4%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 96%, #02659B 4%);
    background-position: -250px 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 250px 100%;
    border: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #0083CA;
    color: #0e6252;
    margin: 0px 25px 10px 0px;
    width: 250px;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.64, 0.09, 0.08, 1);
}

.selectInput:focus
{
    background-position: 0 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

hi paulie D i tried this on my chrome browser and it was working perfectly. the reason why it didnt play the transition when you clicked on another element while the first element was still selected is because  the transition is on the SELECT element which happens when its focused, and since you are still selecting a particular element of the SELECT element(option element) it means the focus is still on the SELECT element and as such you wont notice the transition.